# how can I use two columns as group headers?

Tags: ag-grid

this is my current situation:

| user ID | User Name | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 > |  |  |
|  | UserNr1 | 33 |
|  | UserNr1 | 22 |
| 0002 > |  |  |
|  | UserNr2 | 12 |
|  | UserNr2 | 20 |

What i want to achieve is

| user ID | User Name | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | UserNr1 > |  |
|  |  | 33 |
|  |  | 22 |
| 0002 | UserNr2 > |  |
|  |  | 12 |
|  |  | 20 |

This way, groups should be sortable by user ID and User Name.

Can someone help me with this?

Example data in JSON:

```
[
  {
    "userId": "0001",
    "userName": "UserNr1",
    "stats": "33"
  },
  {
    "userId": "0001",
    "userName": "UserNr1",
    "stats": "22"
  },
  {
    "userId": "0002",
    "userName": "UserNr2",
    "stats": "12"
  },
  {
    "userId": "0002",
    "userName": "UserNr2",
    "stats": "20"
  },
]
```

Comment: so you want to group by 2 items? Take a look at [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grouping/#example-default-row-grouping) example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I already checked that example and it is not the correct solution. In my example, User ID and User Name are always the same couple of values (e.g. 0001 will always have User Name UserNr1). Also I need to sort groups by User ID or User Name

Comment: please post an extract of your data

Comment: EDIT: provided example data in json